# Error in nativequery with spatial function in spring boot JPARepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have following query in Spring JPARepository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id, feature_name, ST_AsText(geom) AS geom FROM feature WHERE " +
            "geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(8.832000, 48.493640, 8.832012, 48.493659, 4326)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Feature> getWithinBoundingBox();
```

It gives error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Received object of type java.lang.String; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received object of type java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
```

Is this wrong way of writing spatial query?findAll function works fine though.

Comment: I think I got the cause. Field in my entity class is jts.Geometry, while query has string value(as it uses ST_AsText).

Comment: `ST_AsText` return Text representation  means string of the geometry type

Comment: You might want to add tags for your database and spatial data to the question because this has almost nothing to do with [spring-data-jpa] and nothing at all with [spring-boot].

Also please include the full stack trace.